# Play video from StorageFile in Windows phone silverlight 8.1?

Tags: c#, silverlight, video

How can I set the source of a MediaElement after selecting a video from the gallery of the phone?

When the debug arrived in the instruction (using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(video.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, isf) is generate an exception "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream", i can't understand why.

This is the code:

```
    private void btn_Crea_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();           
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;  
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;        
        openPicker.ContinuationData["Operation"] = "UpdateVideo";//"UpdateProfilePicture";
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".3GP");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".MP4");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".WMV");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".AVI");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".MOV");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".3G2");
        openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
   }

  public void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
  {
        if ((args.ContinuationData["Operation"] as string) == "UpdateVideo" &&
            args.Files != null &&
            args.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            StorageFile file = args.Files[0];
            Singleton.Instance.video = file;
        }
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
  }

  private void addVideo()
  {
        this.video = Singleton.Instance.video;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                { 
                using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(video.Path, FileMode.Open,                      FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, isf)) 
                    {
                        this.videoBox.SetSource(isfs);
                    }
                }
            });
```

}

Comment: are you declaration file type in Package.AppxManifest?